# Cross-debug Windows application on Linux box in Eclipse CDT

Tags: linux, mingw, eclipse-cdt

I'm moved from Windows to Ubuntu Linux, and now I want to set up development environment here. The problem is that I need

1. C/C++ IDE comparable to Visual Studio
2. Way to generate Windows PE binaries
3. Way do debug Windows PE binaries

At first time I tried Code::Blocks. [Here](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php?PHPSESSID=d9a9d6026d3ab34de4115f13c6412708&topic=3343.0) I find guide to setting it up for cross-development so I managed to get "Hello World" compiled and running under Wine. Moreover, debugging worked too.

But then I found that Eclipse + CDT plugin is far more advanced IDE. I spent some time and finally get project compiled and linked.

Now I'm trying to get MinGW Insight version of GDB working within Eclipse CDT. Simple way to use debugger described in Code::Blocks guide won't work anymore. I continue to receive "Error creating session" messages.

So my question is, how I can use MinGW GDB under Wine as debugger back-end in Eclipse? 
Or, what is best IDE for Linux->Windows cross-development?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering that nobody answered this yet.

1. QtCreator. Don't be confused by its name, QtCreator works is pretty well with any kind of C++ code, you don't need to code in Qt to use it. It is just like FOSS Visual Studio: it does even have a syntax checking "on fly".
2. MinGW. Here's not much to say, it is just creates Win PE executables, and it works. It is available in repositories. Note, that a Win GUI applications have special bit in it's PE header set; so, in order to create GUI application with MinGW you have to pass an option `-mwindows` to set this bit.
3. This is a problem. Really: I'm just trying to debug a windows application, and didn't find yet a way to do it. I will shortly recall here what I tried so far, just in order for you to not step on my rakes:

   - **winedbg**. Probably it should work, but for me it didn't. When I set a breakpoint, i.e. like this `br 43`, it says `Unable to add breakpoint (unknown address 7b860807)`.
   - **winedbg**. Yeah, again, but this time we will use it like this `winedbg --gbd` to make it proxying a commands to `gdb`. Probably this is the only way to debug an application, but it have a drawbacks: first, in order to restart an application you have to exit debugger; if you enter `run` it says that the remote target doesn't support this. Second, I have no even idea how to debug a multithreaded application; when I first started this, I stumbled upon an error `Non-stop mode requested, but remote does not support non-stop`, and after setting a breakpoint and starting it says:
     `Cannot insert breakpoint 1.` and `Cannot access memory at address 0x401654`. So, in order to make this work I was needed to rename my `.gdbinit` file *(i.e. non-stop mode is set there)*.
   - **gdb.exe**. I was sure that I found a way: simple usage of a windows version of `gdb` should solve problems; more over, for me, as I am a Emacs guy, it would be absolutely the same as debugging with native gdb. But alas, the windows gdb just didn't work. If I run it, and enter any command, it simply does nothing. It only reacts on <kbd>Ctrl-c</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-z</kbd> commands. Probably I will try on my spare time to ask a question about it on mailing list. Well, now we can't use it...

So what we have do with debug? Most probably seek another Windows debugger that works under *WINE*. If I correctly recall, OllyDbg worked, but I don't know at the moment how to make it show a source code.

Comment: +1 for QtCreator. It works very well with the GCC tool chain.

Comment: I won't yet update the post, rather leave the information in comment: I found how to run `gdb.exe` with wine to make it work properly, it should look like `wineconsole --backend=curses gdb.exe`.

Comment: Just tried in emacs the `gdb.exe`, it is just unusable :(

Comment: I've been using EDB and setting the executable I want to debug to automatically run with WINE. The application seems to behave differently while running in WINE on EDB than it does when running on a windows VM in Ollydb. I think WINE is the limitation here, it looks like you have to run the windows executable on ACTUAL windows in a VM or natively in order to get the same behavior as is if it was running on windows.

Answer (score 0):

you can try [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/).It's a good free, open source 
and Cross Platform Support IDE.

Answer (score -2):

Run Windows in a VM?

Seriously, your question is good, but it's probably not worth spending the time to figure out the answer (especially: since nobody seems to have a ready answer).  If you have real work to do, native Windows or Windows in a VM is the answer.

Comment: I am run a Windows in VM, and this isn't good idea at all, I say, as my PC have just 2Gb RAM. I am sure that this is worth spending time as once I am found it, I can use it anytime and anywhere.